# ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID SUM(MARKS)
FROM MARKS WHERE MARKS>=500
ORDER BY MARKS DESC 
GROUP BY STUDENT_ID;
```

above is my query and i am getting the following error:

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(MARKS)
FROM marks WHERE MARKS>=500
ORDER BY MARKS DESC GROUP BY STUD' at line 1

can anyone help in it.

Comment: Do you need a comma after student_id?  Is your order by in the right place?

Comment: if i placed comma after student_id i am getting the following error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY STUDENT_ID' at line 4

Comment: You have a column called marks in a table called marks? - That's not a good naming convention.

Comment: the query is done according to the requirements they given to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT M.STUDENT_ID, SUM(M.MARKS) AS SUM_MARKS
FROM MARKS M
WHERE M.MARKS>=500  
GROUP BY M.STUDENT_ID
ORDER BY SUM(M.MARKS) DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT M.STUDENT_ID, SUM(M.MARKS) AS SUM_MARKS
FROM MARKS M
WHERE M.MARKS>=500  
GROUP BY M.STUDENT_ID
ORDER BY SUM_MARKS DESC;
```

Comment: The following error occurs:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY MARKS DESC' at line 1

Comment: @Gowtham GR - the error indicates you did not entirely follow the given answer..

Answer (score 0):

Comma after `STUDENT_ID`; the `SELECT` list is a comma delimited list of expressions.

Comment: Although true this won't fix the problem given the order by group by error..